# Python Fabric not able to find substring in string

Tags: python, string, find, substring, fabric

I have 2 lists of identical length. One contains the substrings I want to find, one contains the longer string in which I am trying to find the substring (it will always be at the beginning of the line). The lists I have contain one entry where the substring is not in the string; the second entry has the substring in the string.

However, it looks like python can't figure out when the substring is there or not. I've tried a lot of different ways.

```
if substring in string
if string.find(substring) != -1
if string.startswith(substring) != -1
```

The first two "if"
 statements above always return false. The last "if" statement always returns true.

```
def agentID():
index = 1
while index < 3:
    ID = linecache.getline('/home/me/project/ID', index)
    agentLine = linecache.getline('/home/me/project/agentIDoutput', index)
    str(agentLine)
    if agentLine.startswith('%s' % str(ID)) != -1:
        print("%s: Proper Agent ID %s found in client.keys" % (env.host_string, ID))
        index = index + 1
    else:
        print("I couldn't find %s in the line %s" % (ID, agentLine))
        index = index + 1
```

This seems pretty simple and straightforward. I even tried explicitly converting to strings to ensure I was searching on the same type. That's what I'm thinking my error is, but it seems to interpret them both as strings.

Comment: "abc" in "abcdef" will always work in python

Comment: add `print(repr(ID), repr(agentLine))` before the compare to see what strings you are comparing. And as mentioned below, don't compare for `-1`. `if agentLine.startswith(ID)` should suffice.

Comment: FYI: `.getline()` obviously already returns a string (otherwise you'd encounter `TypeError`s), so you don't need to convert it. But if you did need to, you'd have to use `agentline = str(agentline)` - you need to reassign the result of `str()`.

Comment: You'll find that the lines have `"\n"` in them. Do `ID.strip()` to get a better compare.

Answer (score 0):

`string.startswith()` returns either `True` or `False` which are de facto the integer values `1` and `0`, respectively.

Therefore, `if string.startswith(substring) != -1` will always be `True`.

Apparently, your substring simply isn't present in your string.

Comment: I have no idea because what you indicated worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`print` is your friend. I tried a quick test:

```
>>> import linecache
>>> print(repr(linecache.getline('tmp/testfile.txt', 1)))
'line 1\n'
```

`linecache` gives you the full line including newline. Just strip it off of the end. You had a couple of other problems I cleaned up while I was here

```
def agentID():
    for index in range(1,4):
        ID = linecache.getline('/home/me/project/ID', index).strip()
        agentLine = linecache.getline('/home/me/project/agentIDoutput', index)
        if agentLine.startswith(ID):
            print("%s: Proper Agent ID %s found in client.keys" % (env.host_string, ID))
        else:
            print("I couldn't find %s in the line %s" % (ID, agentLine))
```

Comment: Thanks. I took out the newline and changing correcting the "startswith" was my problem. I read about the "find" method and assuming the values returned (i.e. -1 for false) were the same for the "startwith" method.